# regex pattern to match words of a string

Tags: php, regex, string

I have an Array() of strings , and i have ton compare  it with a part of a word that it have to be the start of one of the words in each string !!!

With an example it will be much better :

```
array("hello word", "lovely child", "i am lost in paradise" )
```

My test word : `"lo"`

After running a foreach  and a Regex i need to have only  : `lovely child, i am lost in paradise`

Hope that i was clear !   i have a real problem with Regex :/

can you help, Thanks

Comment: Hint: Use anchors (`^`). Hint about hint: Google "regular expressions anchors".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) in combination with a regular expression to achieve this:

```
$array = array("hello word", "lovely child", "i am lost in paradise" );
$term = "lo";

// necessary in case $term contains characters with special meaning in a regex
$term = preg_quote($term, '/');

$results = array_filter(
             $array,
             function($el) use($term) {return preg_match('/\b'.$term.'/', $el);}
           );
```

The regular expression uses the [word boundary anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to ensure that the search term appears at the beginning of a word.

Comment: To Rastaking: This is the best solution in the thread, you'll want to try this first.

Comment: + for reading the full question and providing an answer that uses native PHP functions accordingly.

Comment: Hi, can you explain the `use` keywords use here, i am bit confused about it.

Answer (score 1):

an alternative

```
$array = array("hello word", "lovely child", "i am lost in paradise" );

$find='lo';

print_r(preg_grep('/\b'.$find.'/', $array));
```